# Replace text by using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, replace

Excuse me,but i have a list of urls

```
http://.../000.jpg
http://.../001.jpg
http://.../002.jpg
http://.../003.jpg
http://.../004.jpg
http://.../005.jpg
```

I want it to automatically add the "img src" tag by using jquery, but I don't know how.i want the outcome result look like this

```
<img src="http://.../000.jpg" />
<img src="http://.../001.jpg" />
<img src="http://.../002.jpg" />
<img src="http://.../003.jpg" />
<img src="http://.../004.jpg" />
<img src="http://.../005.jpg" />
```

Sorry for my bad English, Thx !!

Comment: what is the format of those urls..?

Comment: That is not a chain of coding.. just a list of urls. Have you made any effort to try it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have an array like this:

```
var imgUrls = [
  'http://.../000.jpg',
  'http://.../001.jpg',
  'http://.../002.jpg',
  'http://.../003.jpg',
  'http://.../004.jpg',
  'http://.../005.jpg'
];
```

Your code should be:

```
for (var index in imgUrls) {
  var img = $('<img />').attr('src', imgUrls[index]);

  // append the image to somewhere you want
  $('body').append(img);
}
```

Or using pure Javascript:

```
for (var index in imgUrls) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = imgUrls[index];

  // append the image to somewhere you want 
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question i think you trying to set the img tag's source attribute dynamically.It can be possible by using jQuery `attr`

```
 $("#imgid").attr("src","http:....jpg");
```

For more info : [jquery 'attr' documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

If you need to set multiple src to different img tag is possible using Jquery 'each' . 
jquery each will handle both array and array object..

**Sample code :**

Consider you having list of array

```
var source = [
  'http://.../000.jpg',
  'http://.../001.jpg',
  'http://.../002.jpg',
  'http://.../003.jpg',
  'http://.../004.jpg',
  'http://.../005.jpg'
];
```

jQuery  [**each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$.each(source,function( key, value ){
    $("#img"+key).attr("src",value);   // here key = 0,1,2,3...   
});
```

Comment: Not my DV, but good quality answers explain *why* their code solves the problem and provide links to relevant documentation. Check the guide [answer]. Good luck!

Comment: @brasofilo Ok i understood but do you think the question is clear to answer ..?

Comment: I didn't even look at the question, I made my comment from the Low Quality Review queue where your answer appeared for being too short and mostly code-only...

Comment: @brasofilo I updated the code with proper explanation now.. thanks brasofilo